# iphone:Notification alert doesnt work in device while sending the rich push message in Urban Airship

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

In Urban airship when i send the rich push message notification doesn't show.while the mail send file.
In my app i have to implement the urban airship rich push notification but when i sending the message message will sent fine to the app but notification alert doesn't work.
I have also check the notification in setting but my app also not available in the notification in setting.

Comment: Hi can you please post some code?